# Handle Huge Data in Jasper Reports - pagining

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

I want to handle huge data in creating PDF, I know there is a thing called Virtualizers in Jasper Reports, but i don't know how to handle the out of memory exception that is fired when i retrieve the data from the  DAOs, I don't know how to implement pagination in Jasper reports datasources.

Answer (score 1):

To understand Virtualizers you can read "Large File Support" section of Jasper Reports Ultimate Guide (available here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation).

Example of JRSwapFileVirtualizer usage can be found here:
[how to select and configure a JasperReports virtualizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293193/how-to-select-and-configure-a-jasperreports-virtualizer).

If you're still running out of memory, you may need to increase the memory limit using -Xmx JVM option (in server startup script or eclipse run configuration arguments - depends on your environment), for example:

```
-Xmx1024M
```

Comment: I need something to load data into the datasource by chuncks, my problem is i am loading alot of records which might get to millions of rercords, to single datasource.  I am asking about pagining the datasource in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom implementation of JRDatasource and a Virtualizer, Your implementation of JRDatasource should load data in chunks

You can set net.sf.jasperreports.jdbc.fetch.size in jasperreports.properties too, if you are using JRResultSetDataSource

Comment: This has been there for quite sometime that i forgot about it. Thx anyway. I hope this post would help someone