# Is there any one who has successfully generated report with jasper from more than 1 million rows from mysql db?

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

Setup:
Jasperreports: 5.6.1
RAM allocated for JVM: 1536MB(~1.5GB)
Server: tomcat

Requirement:
I want to add support for huge report(more than 1 million records from db table) generation with jasper,For that,yes,I know there is some thing called Virtualizers which can be used to do this job.
Now I tried with [JRSwapFileVirtualizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRSwapFileVirtualizer.html) most of the time,since this is the only virtualizer which is efficient among others.
Below are my efforts I made to try to make it work(but it didn't :()

1. Tried with different block size,min increment count and no of pages combination,But I it doesn't help.[link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1035296/jrswapfilevirtualizer-parameters)
2. Tried while setting ignore pagination to false with point 1.
3. Tried with this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476535/handle-huge-data-in-jasper-reports-pagining)
4. Tried with cached images,subreports
5. Tried without sub report,just a single report(But I also need sub reports in my report ,still I tried just to check if it still generates the report)

I tried almost every possible approach I came through every forum.The jasper documentation doesn't give much information about virtualizers,neither the jasper guide nor the API part have sufficient info.
I just want to ask ,Is there any one who is using the virtualizers to generate more than 1 million records report with jasper,would you mind to share your approach how you are doing it.

Comment: `Before you downvote I have some points to make` - I have to disappoint you :) +1

Comment: @AlexK ,No offence, I have seen some questions downvoted by just seeing the heading.So i also thought that some one will see the virtualizer ,etc, in heading and just downvote it.

Comment: Did you try to make profiling?